# Integrate $dx$ over interval $a\le x \le b$ instead of just $b-a$

Tags: integration, physics, mathematical-physics

In the [Wikipedia article on the wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function#Definition_.28one_spinless_particle_in_1d.29) it's stated that the probability of a spin-less particle in 1D space being found in the interval $a\le x \le b$ at time $t$, where $x$ is the position, given the particle's wave function $\psi (x,t)$, is defined as the integral:
$$
P_{a\le x \le b}(t)=\int_a^b dx |\psi (x,t)|^2
$$
Sticking to the math part instead of the physics part, I don't understand why there's an integral. I know that $\int dx=\int 1dx=x+C$, which means that the integral part of this function just evaluates to $b-a$. Why didn't they just write that?

Of course, given that Wikipedia isn't the *greatest* source of information, I am assuming that the math on Wikipedia is accurate.

Comment: The notation needs getting used to. What they mean is $\int_a^b |\psi(x,t)|^2 \,dx$

Comment: @Thomas If you would post an answer with (if you have time) an explanation of why this notation is used (or a link or keyword to search), I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: ;-) I do know that physicists are using this notation, but I for sure don't have any explanation for the why. Thanks for the offer, though.

Comment: @Arc676: why not ? All that is on the right of the big "S" is the integrand, and a product is commutative. [Even though this notation is purely conventional.]

Comment: While my knowledge on the workings of calculus is quite basic, I've learned that the $dx$ marks the end of the actual integration (e.g. in $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin xdx+2$ the $+2$ doesn't get integrated.

Comment: @Arc676: right, conventionally the multiplication takes precedence over addition and so does the integral sign. For the same reason, $\int 2+x\,dx$ or $\int 2+dx\,x$ would have no meaning.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Perhaps we misunderstand each other. I would integrate your example as $\frac{x^2}{2}+2x+C$. Why do you say it has no meaning?

Comment: Indeed, I would say it has no meaning. $dx$ doesn't act as a closing delimiter.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see. I was forgetting that the $dx$ is actually a term. But if it doesn't act as a closing delimiter, how do you know where the integral stops? Just simply order of operations?

Comment: @Arc676: operator precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of notation. What they mean is $\int\limits_a^b |\psi (x,t)|^2 \mathbb{d}x$.

Such notation is particularly usefull when dealing with multiple integral: $\int \mathbb{d}x \int \mathbb{d}y \int \mathbb{d}z f(x,y,z)$ is a bit cleaner then $\int\int\int f(x,y,z) \mathbb{d}x \mathbb{d}y \mathbb{d}z$ if we try to understand which limits refer to a particular variable under integration.

Another point for this notation from differential geometry point of view is the fact that $f(x)\mathbb{d}x$ is a differential 1-form, which is the function $f(x)$ and the 1-form $\mathbb{d}x$ multiplied; here the multiplication of forms and functions is commutative simply by notation (much as multiplying a vector by a scalar).

Comment: So essentially the $dx$ is a term and it gets multiplied by $|\psi (x,t)|^2$ so they can switch positions?

Comment: @Arc676 Yes, kind of. Note that such notation can often cause ambiguity and I recommend using it only where it is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a specific situation as an example.

We don't take for granted that $|\psi(x)|^{2}=1$ more that in some scenario (like for example the quantum mechanical particle in a box of width $[0,a]$) $\psi(x)=B \sin \left( \frac{n \pi x}{a} \right) $ for some constants $B, n$ and $a$.

In this instance an integral exists such that
$$\int_{0}^{a}B^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\frac{n \pi x}{a} \right)^{2} dx=1$$

From which can be readily computed that the constant $B=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{a}$

Comment: I doubt that this is related to what has been asked.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and time (and great username) but this is really more solving for the wave function in a given situation, not really the notation and why it's written that way.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you left out some information. A couple of lines above on the Wikipedia page, it was stated that
$$\left|\Psi(x,t)^2\right| = \Psi(x,t)^*\Psi(x,t) = \rho(x,t),$$
and that this is interpreted as the probability density that the particle is at $x$.
Thus
$$P_{a\leq x\leq b} (t) = \int_a^bdx\left|\Psi(x,t)\right|^2 = \int_a^b \rho(x,t)\,dx.$$
Presumably, $\rho(x,t) \neq 1$. Meaning therefore
$$\int_a^b\rho(x,t)\,dx \neq \int_a^b 1\,dx \neq b-a.$$

Comment: I think the OP is confused about the position of the $dx$ symbol in the integral (why does it precede the integrand).

Comment: I don't understand how the $|\psi (x,t)|^2$ got moved from after the $dx$ to before it. Or is it actually $d(x|\psi (x,t)|^2)$? (Yes, as commented question is really more about the notation)